# Finding select menu value in submitted form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

I have several forms on the same page.  All have a select menu in them.  When the user submits any form I would like to test the value of that form's select menu but I can't seem to get the right syntax to select the submitted form's menu's value.

This is what I've tried:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    console.log($(this).filter(":selected").val());
    return false;
});
```

I've also tried `.children` in place of filter with no better results.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `console.log($(this).find("select option:selected").val());`

Comment: Try with: `$(this).find('select :selected').val()`

Comment: Well that worked....dang I was so close.  Put it as an answer and I'll give you credit Tushar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

`console.log($(this).find("select option:selected").val());`

Answer (score 0):

try this to get the selected value from the drop down

```
$('select.foo option:selected').val();
```